# If I add 360 months to begin_date, How can I accurately obtain end_date using a lookup dimension table?

Tags: sql, database, date, informix, date-arithmetic

EDIT: begin_date and end_date are type DATE columns in any table.

I have the following dimension table which provides how many total days each month has for years 1980 through 2500:

```
CREATE TABLE total_days
    (
from_date     DATE,
to_date       DATE,
days_in_month SMALLINT
    );

from_date   to_date     days_in_month
1980-01-01  1980-01-31  31
1980-02-01  1980-02-29  29
...
2500-11-01  2500-11-30  30
2500-12-01  2500-12-31  31
```

How should I construct an SQL query to obtain an accurate end_date if I were to add 360 months to begin_date?.. Do I need to alter the dimension table in any way to achieve my goal?

EDIT: The date arithmetic must be performed without using any native SQL date arithmetic functions. It must be done by looking up the begin_date in the dimension table.

Comment: What are th eparameters? A date and the `360 months`?

Comment: yes, add 360 months to begin_date and determine the end_date by using the fact table. begin_date is a column in any other table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you've got your reasons - Here's a very simple hack -
**Assuming that the fact table has a row for every month -** 
Add a new column that represents monthnumber, start it at 1 and autoincrement it up chronolgically ordered, **not** starting over with each year.

```
SELECT B.* 
FROM SO_total_days2 A
INNER JOIN SO_total_days2 B ON B.monthnumber = A.monthnumber + 360
WHERE A.from_date =  '2010-01-01'

from_date   to_date     days_in_month monthnumber
1980-01-01  1980-01-31  31    1
1980-02-01  1980-02-29  29    2
1980-03-03  1980-03-31  31    3
...
1981-01-01  1981-01-31  31    13
1981-12-01  1981-12-31  31    24
...
1985-01-01  1985-01-31  31    49
1985-12-01  1985-12-31  31    60
```

Comment: My thoughts exactly! If date arithmetics are banned, they just have to be replaced by a different kind of arithmetics (integral in this case).

Comment: Reasons?.. 1)Native SQL month functions are not accurate, some even produce invalid dates. 2)Native functions are not portable. 3)Fact table allows for defining rules to control results. 4)Faster performance with fact table?

Comment: I wouldn't even call this a hack. An ordinal value for month has many benefits, and I wouldn't dream of creating a time dimension without such fields at every level of the hierarchy.

Comment: @Frank - wasn't picking on you - for my minimal date needs, date functions work fine - but you obviously have different needs more dependent on dates than I do - hence the "Guess you've got your reasons".

Comment: @Frank: There's no way a fact table will be faster than date arithmetic. The DATETIME arithmetic in the latest Informix servers (11.70.xC5 or later) is revised so that if you add N months to a date, it will generate the last day of the month rather than an invalid date. The cost is that if you do, for example, `DATE('2012-01-31') + 1 UNITS MONTH` and then subtract `1 UNITS MONTH`, you get back `2012-01-29`. That is, adding N months and subtracting N months from the result (or subtracting then adding) need not be an identity operation. The ADD_MONTHS() function works in earlier versions too.

Comment: I wouldn't begin to think I could come up with something faster/better than functions that have been around for x years, tested by x users, and improved/improved upon.  That being said, I don't have to deal with multiple RDBMs.  The problems I've seen with date functions have come from progr's misuse/understnding & not the functions - So throw in multi DB vendors.  We've seen people migrating to SQL from ORACLE  & the date functions can be a switch/big learning curve, behaving differently from what dev expects. Right or wrong in our opinion, the question is how to solve the task without them.

Comment: @Jonathan: begin_date is a datatype DATE. Does ADD_MONTHS() support DATE types?.. My fact table would have 520 nrows (row length = 17) for all the months in years 1980 through 2500. Indexing on from_date and to_date. I wouldn't think there would be much overhead difference by letting the server do the work, especially if this fact table is in memory, plus gain the benefit of customizing the results and achieve more DB portability?

Comment: @Frank, yes  ADD_MONTHS() supports DATE and DATETIME types.

Answer (score 2):

this is what i imagine your "fact table" looks like:

```
declare @dt datetime
    set @dt = '7-1-2012'

;
with date_table as  (
        select  @dt as [Start Date],
                dateadd(d,-1,dateadd(mm,1,@dt)) as [End Date],
                datepart(d,dateadd(d,-1,dateadd(mm,1,@dt))) as [Days]

        union ALL

        select  dateadd(mm, 1, [Start Date]) as  [Start Date],
                dateadd(d,-1,dateadd(mm,1,dateadd(mm, 1, [Start Date]))) as [End Date], 
                datepart(d,dateadd(d,-1,dateadd(mm,1,dateadd(mm, 1, [Start Date])))) as [Days]

        from    date_table
        where   dateadd(mm, 1, [Start Date]) <= dateadd(m,500,@dt))

select  [Start Date], [End Date], [Days]
into    #temp
from    date_table

option (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

this is selecting the dates.  (notice how there is no DATEADD or DATEPART included in these statements)

```
select  finish.[Start Date], finish.[End Date], finish.[Days]
from    (select rownum
         from   (select [Start Date], [End Date], [Days], row_number() over (order by [Start Date]) as rownum
                    from    #temp) as x
         where  x.[Start Date] = '2012-07-01 00:00:00.000' ) as start 

        join    (select [Start Date], [End Date], [Days], 
                        row_number() over (order by [Start Date]) as rownum
                 from   #temp) as finish
            on finish.rownum = start.rownum + 360
```

i read your comments down below... if you're trying to sum up the days or something this is how you could do it:  (so starting with July 1, 2012 and going for 360 months... the date_diff_days result would be the total number of days for the 360 months... using that #temp table i made... which i assume is similar to your fact table... I got 10957 days)

```
select  sum(dayscount.[Days]) as date_diff_days
from    (select rownum
         from   (select [Start Date], [End Date], [Days], row_number() over (order by [Start Date]) as rownum
                    from    #temp) as x
         where  x.[Start Date] = '2012-07-01 00:00:00.000' ) as start 

        join    (select [Start Date], [End Date], [Days], 
                        row_number() over (order by [Start Date]) as rownum
                 from   #temp) as finish
            on finish.rownum = start.rownum + 360

        join (select    [Start Date], [End Date], [Days], 
                        row_number() over (order by [Start Date]) as rownum
                 from   #temp) as dayscount
            on dayscount.rownum >= start.rownum and 
                dayscount.rownum < finish.rownum
```

Comment: nope, it has to be done without using any native SQL date arithmetic functions like DATEADD or DATEPART you are using in your example. it has to be done using the fact table I described in my question.

Comment: i'm not using DATEADD or DATEPART in the actual select statements.  they are just used where i build the temp table that is equivalent to your "fact table."  do you see the two select statements that are apart from the CTE?

Answer (score 2):

If I were to be doing database agnostically, I'd change the  fact table a bit:

```
CREATE TABLE total_days
(
  year          INT,
  month         TINYINT,
  from_date     DATE,
  to_date       DATE,
  days_in_month SMALLINT
);

year  month  from_date   to_date     days_in_month
------------------------------------------------
1980    1    1980-01-01  1980-01-31   31
1980    2    1980-02-01  1980-02-29   29
...
2500   11    2500-11-01  2500-11-30   30
2500   12    2500-12-01  2500-12-31   31
```

Then you could use something like:

```
SELECT td.* 
FROM 
      total_days AS td 
   CROSS JOIN
      ( SELECT year, month
        FROM total_days 
        WHERE from_date <= @StartingDate 
          AND @StartingDate <= to_date
      ) AS st
   CROSS JOIN
      ( SELECT 360 AS add_months ) AS param
WHERE td.year = st.year + ( st.month -1 + add_months ) / 12
  AND td.month = 1 + ( st.month - 1 + add_months ) % 12 )
;
```

or the simpler (but a bit harder to optimize for efficiency:

```
WHERE 12 * td.year + td.month = 
      12 * st.year + st.month + add_months
```

Comment: You're on the right track!.. Would it be better to have year_month as one column e.g. 198001?.. So you're saying add year and month columns to use as an indexing method to determine which year/month the begin_date falls in and then add the 360 months from that particular year/month?

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't like month and year in one column. It would make calculation more complex

Comment: If you want one column, add that `(12*year + month)`, either as a hard column or a computed (persisted) one, so you can index it.

Comment: ok thanks!.. I feel this is a better method for more accurately arriving at an end_date as opposed to using built-in SQL functions, which I'm not sure how different DB vendors are implementing their logic. It also makes the code more portable!.. The other alternative would be to define each month as having 30.4375 days (365.25 days / 12 months) and rounding the result to the nearest date, but that might not be accurate enough!

Answer (score 1):

Why the fact table?  Most DBs have native support for date/time manipulation.  In MS SQL Server, you would do this with [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx).

I see you tagged your question with "informix" but didn't specify any version details in your question.  [Here's an ADD_MONTHS function from IBM Informix 11.50.](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v115/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1531.htm)

Comment: Some DBs do not provide valid dates with functions like ADD_MONTHS() or MONTHS_BETWEEN(). I'd rather use a fact table than rely on any built-in SQL date arithmetic functions. This way, the DBs version would be irrelevant.

Comment: Well, for starters, adding a quantity of number of months is an ambiguous operation.  How long is "a month"?  As your fact table shows, any given month can be different.  What if you are starting on Jan 31 and end on a February date?  Should you snap back to the 28th?  What if it's a leap year?  There are different connotations, so that's why people revert back to the built-in functions.  At least there, you have some standardization.  If you're going to do it yourself, you have to account for all of these things, and it gets complicated quickly and can lead to unexpected bugs.

Comment: that is why I'm using a fact lookup table which contains the total number of days for each month of years 1980 through 2500. Since months have variable number of days, I am basing my date arithmetic on adding the total number of days in 360 months, depending on what the begin_date is.

Comment: Then do a query on your fact table to sum the days from the top x rows where >= your start date and add the result to your start.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [interval](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

```
mysql> SELECT '2008-12-31 23:59:59' + INTERVAL 1 month;
+------------------------------------------+
| '2008-12-31 23:59:59' + INTERVAL 1 month |
+------------------------------------------+
| 2009-01-31 23:59:59                      |
+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select now();
+---------------------+
| now()               |
+---------------------+
| 2012-07-03 12:27:46 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT now() + INTERVAL 30 month;
+---------------------------+
| now() + INTERVAL 30 month |
+---------------------------+
| 2015-01-03 12:27:49       |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

EDIT:

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('01,5,2013','%d,%m,%Y') + interval 30 month;
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('01,5,2013','%d,%m,%Y') + interval 30 month |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| 2015-11-01                                              |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

EDIT 2:

```
mysql> show create table tiempo;
+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table  | Create Table                                                                                   |
+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| tiempo | CREATE TABLE `tiempo` (
  `fecha` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select fecha + interval 20 month from tiempo;
+---------------------------+
| fecha + interval 20 month |
+---------------------------+
| NULL                      |
| 2001-10-02 02:02:02       |
+---------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: cannot use INTERVAL, the data is in DATE type and cannot be converted to DATETIME.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the from date exactly as it is listed and you are always adding months, could you use this:

```
SELECT max (to_date)
  FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY from_date) AS Row,
                from_date,
                to_date,
                days_in_month
         FROM total_days
        WHERE from_date > '1/1/1982'
      GROUP BY from_date, to_date, days_in_month) MyDates
 WHERE Row <= 360
```